# for_each on terraform with Azure Load Balancer

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-load-balancer

I am trying to create an Azure Load Balancer to build multiple front end ip in the az load balancer that leverages public ips for azure availability zones:

This is my file structure :

```
terraform-azurem-loadbalncer/
┣ locals.tf
┣ output.tf
┣ tlz-lb.tf
┣ tlz-pip.tf
┗ variables.tf
```

What I am trying to do is quite like the post [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58907705/how-to-use-terraform-dynamic-block-to-build-multiple-front-end-ip-in-the-az-load):
This is my tlz-pip.tf

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "tlz_public_ip" {
  name                    = "${local.prefix}-${local.resource_type}-${var.pip_name}-${var.environment}"
  resource_group_name     = var.resource_group_name
  location                = var.location
  allocation_method       = var.allocation_method
  sku                     = var.pip_sku
  ip_version              = var.ip_version
  idle_timeout_in_minutes = try(var.idle_timeout_in_minutes, 30)
  domain_name_label       = var.generate_domain_name_label ? "${local.prefix}-${local.resource_type}-${var.pip_name}-${var.environment}" : var.domain_name_label
  reverse_fqdn            = try(var.reverse_fqdn, null)
  zones                   = try(var.zones, null)
  tags = merge(
    {
      "Name" = "${local.prefix}-${local.resource_type}-${var.pip_name}-${var.environment}"
    },
    var.tags
  )
}
```

This is my tlz-lb.tf:

```
resource "azurerm_lb" "tlz-lb-navigator-dev" {
  name                = "${local.prefix}-${local.resource_type}-${var.environment}-${var.location}"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  sku                 = var.lb_sku

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = var.frontend_ip_name
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.tlz_public_ip.id
  }

  dynamic "frontend_ip_configuration" {
     for_each = azurerm_public_ip.tlz_public_ip
     content {
       name                 = "config_${each.value.name}" 
       public_ip_address_id = each.value.id
    }
  }
}
resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "tlz-lb-backendpool-dev" {
  name            = var.backend_address_pool
  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.tlz-lb-navigator-dev.id
}
resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "tlz-lb-rule" {
  resource_group_name            = var.resource_group_name
  loadbalancer_id                = azurerm_lb.tlz-lb-navigator-dev.id
  name                           = var.load_balancing_rule
  protocol                       = "Tcp"
  frontend_port                  = 443
  backend_port                   = 443
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = var.frontend_ip_name
}
resource "azurerm_lb_nat_rule" "tlz-nat-rule" {
  count                          = var.nblinuxvms
  resource_group_name            = var.resource_group_name
  loadbalancer_id                = azurerm_lb.tlz-lb-navigator-dev.id
  name                           = var.nat_rule_name
  protocol                       = "Tcp"
  frontend_port                  = 80
  backend_port                   = 80
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "config_${azurerm_public_ip[count.index].tlz_public_ip.name}"
}
resource "azurerm_lb_probe" "tlz-lb-probe" {
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  loadbalancer_id     = azurerm_lb.tlz-lb-navigator-dev.id
  name                = var.health_probe_name
  port                = 22
}
```

And this is my variables.tf:

```
#Public IP configuration
variable "location" {
  description = "(Required) The location/region where the virtual network is created"
  default     = "centralus"
}
variable "environment" {
  description = "(Required) The environment platform in which resources will be deployed."
  default     = "stage"
}
variable "public_ip_address_id" {
  default     = ""
  description = "public ip address id"
}
variable "resource_group_name" {

  description = "resource group name"
}
variable "tags" {
  description = "(Required) Map of tags to be applied to the resource"
  type        = map(any)
}
variable "pip_name" {
  description = "(Required) The name for public ip address."
}
variable "allocation_method" {
  default     = "Dynamic"
  description = "(Required) Defines the allocation method for this IP address. Possible values are Static or Dynamic."
}
variable "ip_version" {
  description = "The IP Version to use, IPv6 or IPv4."
  default     = "IPv4"
}
variable "idle_timeout_in_minutes" {
  description = "Specifies the timeout for the TCP idle connection. The value can be set between 4 and 30 minutes."
  default     = 30
}
variable "generate_domain_name_label" {
  description = "The flag to control creation of domain label."
  default     = false
}
variable "domain_name_label" {
  description = "If a domain name label is specified, an A DNS record is created for the public IP in the Microsoft Azure DNS system."
  default     = null
}
variable "reverse_fqdn" {
  description = " A fully qualified domain name that resolves to this public IP address."
  default     = ""
}
variable "zones" {
  description = "A collection containing the availability zone to allocate the Public IP in."
  default     = null
}


#Load Balancer

variable "lb_sku" {
  type        = string
  default     = "Basic"
  description = "(Optional) The SKU of the Azure Load Balancer. Accepted values are Basic and Standard. Defaults to Basic."
}
variable "pip_sku" {
  type        = string
  default     = "Basic"
  description = "(Optional) The SKU of the Public IP. Accepted values are Basic and Standard. Defaults to Basic."
}
variable "frontend_ip_name" {
  type        = string
  default     = ""
  description = "(Required) Specifies the name of the frontend ip configuration."
}
variable "backend_address_pool" {
  type        = string
  default     = ""
  description = "(Required) Specifies the name of the Backend Address Pool"
}
variable "load_balancing_rule" {
  type        = string
  default     = ""
  description = "(Required) Specifies the name of the LB Rule."
}
variable "nat_rule_name" {
  type        = string
  default     = ""
  description = "(Required) Specifies the name of the NAT Rule."
}
variable "health_probe_name" {
  type        = string
  default     = ""
  description = "(Required) Specifies the name of the Probe."
}
variable "nblinuxvms" {
  type        = number
  default     = "2"
  description = "NUmber of VMs to be attached."
}
```

This is the error I am getting for tlz-lb.tf:
Error: Invalid reference

```
  on FARMERS-TLZ-TFE-PMR/terraform-azurerm-stage-lb/terraform-azurem-loadbalncer/tlz-lb.tf line 41, in resource "azurerm_lb_nat_rule" "tlz-nat-rule":
  41:   frontend_ip_configuration_name = "config_${azurerm_public_ip[count.index].name}"

A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute
access, specifying the resource name.
```

I am not sure what might be causing this error since I have followed the post mentioned before, please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your code formatting here is similar to what you are provisioning out of `tlz-lb.tf` then this is due to the dynamic block being created outside of the resource block.

I would suggest cleaning up your code to be something similar to below where the dynamic block is inside the resource block. Adjust spacing as needed on your end.

```
resource "azurerm_lb" "tlz-lb-navigator-dev" {
  name                = "${local.prefix}-${local.resource_type}-${var.environment}-${var.location}"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  sku                 = var.lb_sku

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = var.frontend_ip_name
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.tlz_public_ip.id
  }
}

  dynamic "frontend_ip_configuration" {
     for_each = azurerm_public_ip.tlz_public_ip
     content {
       name                 = "config_${each.value.name}" 
       public_ip_address_id = each.value.id
    }
}
```

Edit:

Also in the dynamic block when iterating you most likely will need to use `frontend_ip_configuration.value.<ATTRIBUTE>` instead of `each.value.<ATTRIBUTE>`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have updated the code based on your suggestion, but I seem to be getting the same answer, I have updated the question as well for your reference. TIA.

Comment: May need to update your opening and closing `{ }`. The static `frontend_ip_configuration` has a closing curly brace to close off the resource block so you'll just need to update the static and dynamic block to all fit within the same resource block for `azurerm_lb`.

Comment: Thanks rk, that worked like a charm, I got a few more errors that I have updated in the question please suggest any changes if any.

Comment: Try to use `[count.index]` instead of just `count`.

Comment: count.index issue got resolved, thanks a ton. Any idea on how we can resolve the Invalid reference error? TIA. I feel it's got something to do with syntax.

Comment: Could it be because I am not referencing resource "azurerm_public_ip" "tlz_public_ip" , in "tlz-lb.tf" hence it is not able to get the data ?

Comment: @PranaySinghParihar Yes if it's coming out of a different `.tf` file that is not in the same directory as `tlz-lb.tf` is located then that is most likely what is causing the problem. If these are in the same directory let's try to remove the `config_` and only pass in `azurerm_public_ip[count.index].tlz_public_ip.name`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233973/discussion-between-pranay-singh-parihar-and-rk92).